# Error in building wlan and wirelesshart module in inet using omnetpp

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am working on a project using INET framework to implement coexistence management between Wlan and wirelessHart. The concept used to implement is SNMP, I need some help and references to proceed with this project. So please help me out with some links and website to study and refer. Now I have an error which cannot solved and it is shown in the picture:

[image: error in simulation].

Please help me sort out the problem.

Comment: Are you asking for a tutorial recommendation, or are you seeking help regarding your error? The former is not in scope of Stack Overflow, the later requires you to provide enough info for us to be able to help you - see [mcve].

Comment: I need a suggestion how to implement coexistence management using SNMP in INET? Any kind of suggestion like examples, a tutorial to implement SNMP in INET because I know the concept of SNMP just require some help to write my code. I am doing designing part so the error is difficult for me to debug because I'm beginner in omnetpp.